# Adding one line-break plus one row of text underneath - in a single row, single segment, codepiece

Tags: bash

I want to add a **one line-break plus one row of text underneath**, in a single row, single segment, codepiece.

A single row, multi segment way I know is this:

```
sudo bash -c "echo '' >> /etc/bash.bashrc" && sudo bash -c "echo 'alias www=\"cd /var/www/html\"' >> /etc/bash.bashrc"
```

This is a single row, but not a single segment way (a `&&` is needed).

Another way on the other hand, [heredocument](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Here_document) is of single segment (no `&&`) but of multiple rows, and I'm looking for a single row, single segment way. Do you know any?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some one-liners for you to play with and make them work with `sudo`:

```
printf '%s\n' a '' 'alias www="cd /var/www/html"' . ,p q | ed -s /etc/bash.bashrc
```

same with a here-string:

```
ed -s /etc/bash.bashrc <<< $'a\n\nalias www="cd /var/www/html"\n.\n,p\nq'
```

replace `,p` with `w` to edit in-place; or

```
sed -e '${G;G;s|$|alias www="cd /var/www/html"|' -e'}' /etc/bash.bashrc
```

add `-i` (`gnu sed`) or `-i ''` (`bsd sed`) to edit in-place; or

```
cat <<< $'\nalias www="cd /var/www/html"' >> /etc/bash.bashrc
```

Answer (score 4):

```
printf '\nalias www="cd /var/www/html"\n' | sudo tee -a /etc/bashrc
```

[`printf`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/printf.html) interprets C-style backslash escapes including `\n`. `tee -a` opens the given file for appending and writes the input it receives into it.

You could also apply that to your existing `bash -c`:

```
sudo bash -c "printf '\\nalias www=\"cd /var/www/html\"\\n' >> /etc/bashrc"
```

which uses no top-level shell operators, if you really want to avoid those.

Comment: `tee` also prints to standard output; you can of course redirect that to `/dev/null` if you wish to avoid this side effect.

Comment: The double quotes are a bit of a hassle. You could use "C-style" single quotes `$'...'` which allow for a backslash-escaped single quote inside the single quotes. That still leaves a bit of backslashitis but at least you can reduce it.